# Resize a scrollview to the size of its parent with swift

Tags: ios, view, uiscrollview, swift2

I am trying to resize my scrollview to the view holding it.if a condition is met. I want to delete my youtube player and then resize the scrollview to match the parent size. I am a bit lost on how to do this. I have tried a few things but nothing works.

What I have set up. 
I have a view with a youtubeplayerview and a scrollview nested inside the view. 
I want to see if there is no video i want to delete the video player and resize the scrollview.

This is what I have so far:

```
    if myVideo.isEmpty
    {
        print("Video is empty")
        //ytPlayer.removeFromSuperview()
        //self.ytPlayer.removeWebView()
        self.ytPlayer.removeFromSuperview()
        //ytPlayer.window?.hidden = true
        self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( self.parentView.frame.size.width, self.parentView.frame.size.height)

    }else{
        //load the video
        ytPlayer .loadWithVideoId(myVideo)

    }
```

Thank for any help with this

Comment: The content size is the size of the virtual area inside the scrollview. You want to either modify the scroll view's `frame` or constraints if you are using autolayout.

Comment: I don't think that the video player is being deleted

Comment: Why do you say that. You are calling removeFromSuperView. Have you set a breakpoint in this code to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes and I changed the color of the box to blue and its still there and the scrollview never resizes either

Comment: Here is what I am using now  self.myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(self.parentView.frame.minX, self.parentView.frame.minY, self.parentView.frame.size.width, self.parentView.frame.size.height)

Comment: You can just say `self.myScrollView.frame=self.parentView.frame` but this will only work if you aren't using autolayout; ie you created the scrollview programatically, not in Interface Builder. Set a breakpoint in this code and confirm that it is being called

Comment: I used an interface builder so thats my issue? Can I not adjust the position then via code?

Comment: You can, but you need to create IBOutlet references to the relevant constraints and modify the constraints